# Unable to update table After Copying Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I make a copy of my database to another database using c#.

Everything looks ok.

However, when i try to insert a row I get this error:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT permission was denied on the object database schema 'dbo'.**

This is my c# code to copy the database:

```
public bool CreateDataBase(string dbName)
{         
        //var connstring = "data source=.;initial catalog=InformedWorker;integrated security=True;";
        var connstring = "Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master";
        var localhost = "localhost";

        try
        {
            Server server = new Server(localhost);



            Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database sourceDatabase = server.Databases["InformedWorkerTemplate"];

            Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database newDatbase = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database(server, dbName);


            var clientDBPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientData"];


            newDatbase.FileGroups.Add(new FileGroup(newDatbase, "PRIMARY"));
            DataFile dtPrimary = new DataFile(newDatbase.FileGroups["PRIMARY"], "PriValue", clientDBPath + "\\" + dbName + ".mdf");
            dtPrimary.Size = 77.0 * 1024.0;
            dtPrimary.GrowthType = FileGrowthType.KB;
            dtPrimary.Growth = 1.0 * 1024.0;

            newDatbase.FileGroups["PRIMARY"].Files.Add(dtPrimary);

            LogFile logFile = new LogFile(newDatbase, "Log", clientDBPath + "\\" + dbName + ".ldf");
            logFile.Size = 7.0 * 1024.0;
            logFile.GrowthType = FileGrowthType.Percent;
            logFile.Growth = 10.0;

            newDatbase.LogFiles.Add(logFile);

            newDatbase.Create();

            Transfer transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase);
            transfer.CopySchema = true;
            transfer.CopyData = true;
            transfer.Options.DriAllKeys = true;
            transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
            transfer.CopyAllViews = true;
            transfer.CopyAllDatabaseTriggers = true;
            transfer.CopyAllDefaults = true;
            transfer.CopyAllFullTextCatalogs = true;
            transfer.CopyAllFullTextStopLists = true;
            transfer.CopyAllPartitionFunctions = true;
            transfer.CopyAllPartitionSchemes = true;
            transfer.CopyAllPlanGuides = true;
            transfer.CopyAllRoles = true;
            transfer.CopyAllRules = true;
            transfer.CopyAllSchemas = true;
            transfer.CopyAllSearchPropertyLists = true;
            transfer.CopyAllSequences = true;
            transfer.CopyAllSqlAssemblies = true;
            transfer.CopyAllStoredProcedures = true;
            transfer.CopyAllSynonyms = true;
            transfer.CopyAllTables = true;
            transfer.CopyAllUserDefinedAggregates = true;
            transfer.CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true;
            transfer.CopyAllUserDefinedFunctions = true;
            transfer.CopyAllUserDefinedTableTypes = true;
            transfer.CopyAllUserDefinedTypes = true;
            transfer.CopyAllUsers = true;
            transfer.CopyAllViews = true;
            transfer.CopyAllXmlSchemaCollections = true;
            transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
            transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
            transfer.DestinationDatabase = newDatbase.Name;
            transfer.CopySchema = true;
            transfer.CopyData = true;
            transfer.Options.DriAllKeys = true;

            StringCollection transferScript = transfer.ScriptTransfer();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand switchDatabase = new SqlCommand("USE [" + newDatbase.Name + "]", conn))
                {
                    switchDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                foreach (string scriptLine in transferScript)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand scriptCmd = new SqlCommand(scriptLine, conn))//, transaction))
                    {
                        int res = scriptCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logging.AddError(ex.ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is my server/api code to add a row (I have bound my DB to Enitity Framework so I change the database)

```
public void Exchange()
    {
        try
        {
            var query = admin.Subscriptions.Where(d => d.CompanyRef == "56f55e3e-deac-4cde-ae4b-83671363a54e").FirstOrDefault();
            if (query != null)
            {
                o.Database.Connection.Open();
                o.Database.Connection.ChangeDatabase(query.DatabaseName);
                o.Customers.Add(new Customer()
                {
                    CompanyName = "CompanyName",
                    CompanyRef = "CompanyRef",
                    CustomerRef = "CustomerRef",
                    DOE = DateTime.Now,
                    Email = "Email",
                    FName = "FName",
                    MobileNo = "MobileNo",
                    Salutation = "Salutation",
                    ServerRef = "ServerRef",
                    ServerTS = DateTime.Now,
                    SName = "SName",
                    TelephoneNo = "TelephoneNo",
                    Active = true


                });
                o.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logging.AddError(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I copy everything from DB to DB so cannot see what else I can do?

Comment: are you restoring it to another server

Comment: @TheGameiswar hello. No I am not all to my local server

Comment: You have assumed your copying was the same as retrieving the same roles and privileges on the DB. Avoid using C# for this as such commands are best handled by a DBA and ought to be encapsulated.

Comment: @clifton_h hi I agree with u but this process has to be automated.

Comment: Since this is SQL Server, use a stored proc to retrieve these in a file or whatever format you require

Comment: Hi would u care to elaborate please? I  not a DBA u c. I would accept as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was making this more difficult for myself than I needed to.

I agree with the other posters about this being a DBA function but I had a requirement for this to be done in managed code.

Also, thanks to Ross Bush (+1) who gave me a starter as to where to look. But, I have to say that these Users were already copied over to the new database.  it was just the mapping permission to the User that was not carried over.

The answer was simple:

```
var localhost = "localhost";
Server srv = new Server(localhost);
Database sourceDatabase = srv.Databases["1407245195"];
var username = @"IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool";
srv.Databases["1407245195"].Roles["db_accessadmin"].AddMember(username);
srv.Databases["1407245195"].Roles["db_backupoperator"].AddMember(username);
srv.Databases["1407245195"].Roles["db_datareader"].AddMember(username);
srv.Databases["1407245195"].Roles["db_datawriter"].AddMember(username);
srv.Databases["1407245195"].Roles["db_ddladmin"].AddMember(username);
srv.Databases["1407245195"].Roles["db_owner"].AddMember(username);
srv.Databases["1407245195"].Roles["db_securityadmin"].AddMember(username);
```

Comment: Be wary of the access method you utilized to read from the Sys data tables. Whatever account used, it has a lot of power in the server, and you ought to guard and encapsulate it from outside influences. This is a primary reason for using procs in that you remove the ability to impersonate the account with access.

Comment: @clifton_h thanks.I can see how that does compromise.  This code is for this 1 server for this type of database,  If I did use a stored procedure and called it from c# though would that not still be a compromise? Thanks for making me think :)

Comment: Np. Lets assume good encryption on the stream for the command. SQL Server allows us to get granular to roles and rights; Create a shell login with only one privilege: `GRANT EXECUTE ON <PROC> TO <user>`. Even better, run the stored proc with a preface  `EXECUTE AS <user/login>`. (Note: roles with sysadmin is almost always NEVER needed and should be avoided) This is verified at the server level. Now you can be even more explicit on how and where access is given (further hiding what the proc actually does). There are other solutions which your DBA should be able to help you with. Cheers

Comment: @clifton_h Many Thaks. I will look into all that. ta

Comment: Note: in case I was misread: you can create the proc with execute as. In other words,the `execute proc` command is run by account A, but the proc uses a different account altogether to actually perform the actions. You can even stack EXECUTE AS statements on top of each other if you wanted to get more granular.

Comment: @clifton_h  I understood what you meant. It looks like a good approch

Answer (score 2):

You have to script your users and/or permissions. If you apply security at the server or instance level then you need to grant access and rights for you sql server users to the database copy that you just made.

You are almost there.

[Managing Users, Roles and Logins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162144.aspx)

You are going to have to access user credentials in your code so be sure to take appropriate caution.

Comment: Thanks but can u provide sample c# code so I can implement this pls?

Comment: One way to do this is to create the SQL commands in SQL Server Management Studio to allocate permissions, test that they work on your copied database, then just run them using "SqlCommand", as your code already does in a few places. But again, this kind of task is much more suited to being all put into a single Stored Procedure, and it would be easier to test & maintain.

Comment: Added SMO document.

Comment: HI, sorry for the delay in my response. I am unsure how to proceed. The users that were in the source database have been copied ok to the destination database. i can see that by viewing the users under Studio Manager?